How to Properly Handle DMA Triggers for Sine Wave Generation in Center-Aligned Mode 2 PWM on STM32?
I'm generating a sine wave using an H-bridge with an STM32 microcontroller, utilizing center-aligned mode 2 PWM generation. In center-aligned mode 2, the DMA triggers twice per PWM cycle: once during the up-counting phase and once during the down-counting phase.
My question is:
Do I need to provide the same value from the lookup table (LUT) to the CCR register for both the up-counting and down-counting phases to avoid distortion?
If I don't provide the same values for up-counting and down-counting phases, how will it affect the smoothness of the sine wave?
What is the best approach to ensure a smooth sine wave generation in this setup?
I want to ensure that the sine wave output is as smooth as possible and is not distorted. Any guidance or best practices for handling DMA and CCR values in center-aligned mode 2 would be greatly appreciated.

You never indicated if you want the output wave frequency to change over time. It's unclear what exactly you're trying to do.

I dont want to change the frequency ,its a unipolar sinew inverter

If you don't need to change frequency, why do you need changing values in the timer? Can't it run with fixed PWM frequency passed through RC filter?

I am  changing the duty cycle only not frequency . finally am using LC filter
